# id3demux "streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)" on certain MP3s

Tags: python-2.7, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm creating a player in Python-GStreamer, on a pretty dated GStreamer 0.10.32, like this:

```
import pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst
import gobject

self.__player = gst.parse_launch(
    'filesrc name="source" location="/file/here.mp3" '
    '! audio/mpeg, mpegversion=1, layer=3 '
    '! ffdec_mp3 '
    '! audioconvert ! audioresample ! volume name="vol" '
    '! alsasink name="sink" sync=false')
```

It works fine, but I never get a tags message from the player's bus. I do need id3 tags.
So I'm replacing caps filter (`audio/mpeg, mpegversion=1, layer=3`) with `id3demux`, and an error appears on certain MP3s: "`streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)`".

Putting `identity` or `queue` in front and linking to them doesn't help with `id3demux`.

For some reason, `mad` element is not available on my platform.

Why won't my second replacement work, or is there another way to get id3 tags from the stream?

**EDIT:** Apparently, this is caused by specific files. No idea yet what is so specific about those MP3s. This also happens when I simply test the pipeline with `gst-launch`.

With GST_DEBUG=2, I'm getting:

```
0:00:00.046048767 32720      0x22388a0 WARN                tagdemux gsttagdemux.c:680:gst_tag_demux_chain:<id3demux0> Downstream did not handle newsegment event as it should
0:00:00.046096615 32720      0x22388a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2625:gst_base_src_loop:<source> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.046106087 32720      0x22388a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2625:gst_base_src_loop:<source> error: streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
```

Replacing `id3demux` with a caps filter back helps, but I never get the tags then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up resorting to `playbin2`. It manages to build a working pipelines that do send tags message somehow.